# Cannot resolve symbol '@drawable

Tags: android, drawable

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgdice1"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="141dp"
        android:layout_column="7"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:onClick="dice1"
        android:src="@drawable/imgdice1" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

At "android:src="@drawable/imgdice1" it says Cannot resolve symbol. I have the images in all of the drawables and it doesn't work. I have a scratch program and it works perfectly on there. When I try to add the imageView on the virtual device it doesn't show the list of my images. 
This is a visual of the problem I am having. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q30tt.jpg

Whole Layout Code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/table">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img1stdice"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:src="@drawable/imgdice1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRollDice"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="10"
        android:text="Roll Dice"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope I can get this issue solved quickly, Thank you. :)

Comment: can you share layout code and imgdice1 image because it look like okay

Comment: @NarendraPrajapati I updated the code to show you the whole layout code.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the image or drawable named "imgdmce1" into your drawable folder. You only have 2 drawables 
1.ic_launcher
2.table
**please add your image inside drable folder in your project**
I think u got some confusion with the drawable drawable name and the imageview id. Both are different